# Tropical Plants Fruiting in Temperate Climates

Tags: fruit-trees, indoors, cold-weather

I live in hardiness zone 4, where not much can survive the winter, but I have been able to grow many tropical plants by bringing them inside before the frost, or by keeping them in my office year round.

I have 2 pineapple plants that are about 3 years old, a pomegranate tree that is about 6 years old, and an orange tree that is about 8 years old.

All of them are very healthy, and mature enough to fruit; the first pineapple plant even came with a pineapple growing when I bought it, but none have shown signs of flowering. I have read that fruiting depends on number of hours of daylight and day/night temperature cycles.

Is there a way I can coax the plants to flower and produce fruit?

Comment: Plants grown indoors even if you place them outside during the summer just do not get enough light/heat/day length they need to produce fruit/flowers.  If you want to get these plants to flower you will have to build a greenhouse with climate controls...taking indoor plants outside on a covered porch truly helps them remain vigorous as an indoor plant.  To produce fruit/flowers you have to have pretty heavy duty light fixtures, steady warmth that never goes below 60 or above 90 degrees Farenheit.  Whatever you are doing is promoting beautiful plants...

Answer (score 5):

Pineapples commercially induced to bloom and fruit by spraying with a dilute solution to 2,4-D, among others, such as various growth hormones, and ethylene gas. (Mentioned by my botany professor -- 40 years ago, as an illustration that toxicity is in the dose)

[Survey of induced flowering in pineapple in brazil](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=s0006-87052005000400001&script=sci_arttext)
Raft of references in the article.

[Paper in the Bromeliad Society journal](http://journal.bsi.org/V15/5/)

I've seen citrus bloom and bear fruit indoors, but usually the smaller ones.  Kumquats and such.

Try on the gardenweb forum, and on the UBC botanical forum.

Answer (score 3):

Would the frequency range of the lndoor lighting have anything to do with the plants growth to fruition? Natural daylight being made up of a range of light frequencies, and indoor lighting is more restricted. Natural daylight bulbs may help whilst your plants are indoors over the winter months.